# How to create an Alias with a Variable inside?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, alias

I want to create an Alias for my Terminal to quick-search inside files.

In Ubuntu is was: `alias gre="egrep -rnw "`. I used it like that `$ gre 'my search string'`.

Now I want this for my local MacBook-Terminal. I found out that I have to use grep only like this `grep -r 'search string' .`

How can I add an Alias like the one in Ubuntu?

I think it's something like this: `alias gre="grep -r $theTerminalParameter ."`

If I test it in the Terminal: `alias test="grep -r $var ."` and check the "content" of that alias with `alias test` i get that information:

`alias test='grep -r  .'` so my Variable doesn't appear in the alias.

How can I use an Alias for that task.

Comment: `alias gre='grep -r'`, and then use it as `gre pattern` or `gre $VAR` :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use alias for arbitrary substitutions. You can use a function instead.

```
function gre() {
  grep -r "$@" .
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me... others may need the information where to store this function: `~/.bash_profile` is the right place. Don't forget to open a new tab to use the changes with `cmd-t` or quit and reopen the terminal.

Comment: @MonTea Sure, but if you familiar with making aliases as is the premise of the question, then functions don't require any additional knowledge. A function can still be manually typed into the shell just like an alias, to take effect only in that session.

Comment: @MonTea it is actually sufficient to source .bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

You can add the line to `~/.bash_profile`

`alias gre='grep -rwn'`

and use it just adding dot after search string

`gre 'search string' .`

to update your current session in case you do not want to close the tab

`source ~/.bash_profile`

which in turn your can alias as well if you like adding new aliases from time to time. `sbash` for example.